# ajaxForm(options) what should be passed to the options?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        target: '#output1', // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit: showRequest, // pre-submit callback 
        success: showResponse // post-submit callback
    };

    $('#myForm1').ajaxForm(options);
});

function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    var queryString = $.param(formData);
    alert('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString);
    return true;
}

function showResponse(responseText, statusText) {
    alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText +
        '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.');
}
```

In the above program what is passed in the option argument?I use the http://jquery.malsup.com/

Answer (score 1):

What is your question?

Please elaborate.

From the [jQuery Form Plugin API Documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api):

> *ajaxForm*
>
> Prepares a form to be
>   submitted via AJAX by adding all of
>   the necessary event listeners. It does
>   not submit the form. Use ajaxForm in
>   your document's ready function to
>   prepare your form(s) for AJAX
>   submission. ajaxForm **takes zero or one
>   argument**. The single **argument can be**
>   either a **callback function or** an
>   **Options Object**. Chainable: Yes.
>
> Note: **You can pass any of the standard
>   $.ajax options to ajaxForm**

Answer (score 0):

target - [#outout1] is the Div which you want to reload.

beforSubmit - action you want to perform before reload

success - action you want to perform after reload

Answer (score 0):

The 'beforeSubmit' callback is invoked with three arguments: the form data in array format, the jQuery object for the form, and the Options Object passed into ajaxForm/ajaxSubmit.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object