# Fix contact form - Messages sent successfully

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, contact-form

I have a landing page in HTML that involves sending data via a contact form. But if you try to use the contact form, when you click the 'Submit' button, you open a new PHP page with 'Success'. How can I do that when I click 'Submit' does not open a page, but a text appears under the 'Send' button with the text 'Messages sent successfully'?

I cannot fix this problem. What should I change in my HTML and my PHP?

Here is an example image of what I would like to do:

[image]

HTML CODE:

```
 <!-- Form -->
            <form class="contact-form" role="form" method="post" action="php/form-process.php">
              <i class="mdi-action-account-box"></i>

              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Nome" required="required">

              <i class="mdi-content-mail"></i>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email"  required="required">

              <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Messaggio" rows="4"  required="required"></textarea>

              <input type="checkbox" name="trattdati" required /> Accetto il trattamento dei miei dati ai sensi del D.Lgs. 196/03<br />
             <input type="checkbox" name="provasoftware" />  Desidero provare il software
<br /><br />
              <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
    style="float:left">Invia</button>

    <div id="success" class="success" style="    color: #009688;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: -16px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;">
              </div>
            </form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // This command is used to initialize some elements and make them work properly
            $.material.init();
            var options = {
                    target:        '#success',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response
                    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback
                    success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback

                    // other available options:
                    //url:       url         // override for form's 'action' attribute
                    //type:      type        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute
                    //dataType:  null        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type)
                    //clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit
                    //resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit

                    // $.ajax options can be used here too, for example:
                    //timeout:   3000
                };

         // pre-submit callback
            function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
                return true;
            }

            // post-submit callback
            function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
                $('.contact-form')[0].reset();
                $('.contact-form').trigger("reset");
            }

            // bind form using 'ajaxForm'
            $('.contact-form').ajaxForm(options);


        });
    </script>
```

PHP FILE:

```
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

// MSG SUBJECT
//if (empty($_POST["msg_subject"])) {
//    $errorMSG .= "Subject is required ";
//} else {
//    $msg_subject = $_POST["msg_subject"];
//}


// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
}


$EmailTo = "bagiacchimarco7@gmail.com";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
//$Body .= "Subject: ";
//$Body .= $msg_subject;
//$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Something went wrong :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi Marco. We discourage links to live websites illustrating a problem, since if a question relies on that, then as soon as the live instance is fixed, the question becomes less useful for future readers. Thus, please put as much detail into the question itself as you can.

Comment: Useful reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Marco, can you alter the `showResponse` function and add `console.log(responseText)` at the start of the function. Also, can you provide a link to the exact `ajaxForm` plugin you are using. Can you see any errors in the Web Console in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Javascript correctly as per the documentation for whatever plugin you are using, you should be able to simply do:

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
    $('#success').html(responseText);
    $('.contact-form')[0].reset();
    $('.contact-form').trigger("reset");
}
```

Again, I'm making assumptions, but `responseText` should contain the data from your PHP page. `#success` looks like the `div` where you want your form feedback to go and the `html` jQuery function will allow you to put the `responseText` into the `#success` div.

Granted the other answers all show ways of doing this without your plugin, but it appears you are using a jQuery plugin.

## EDIT

After reading the documentation on your plugin I think you may just need to add:

```
$('.contact-form').submit(function() { 
    // submit the form 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(); 
    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
    return false; 
});
```

You need to thoroughly read the documentation about all of the plugins you are using.

## EDIT2

Try changing Raj's code to

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault() //Prevent the default action of the form.
    $.post( //Send a POST request to the PHP file via AJAX
        "php/form-process.php", //Path to the PHP file where you want to send the POST
         $(.contact-form).serializeArray().reduce(function(obj, item) {
             obj[item.name] = item.value;
             return obj;
         }, {}), // This takes all the form fields and returns key-value pairs of form data
    function (data) { //data = response from the PHP file. In your case "Sucess"
        if(data==="success"){
                //do something with data. Have assumed you want to append it to a div called "response". You will need to add <div id="success"> </div> below your form
            $('#success').html(data);
        } else {
            $('#success').html("Sorry Try Again"); 
        }
    });
)}
```

Comment: You can find here the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uaf7b7l5x3cupml/landing-page.zip?dl=0 ...
To check the code

Comment: I just found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635836/ajaxformoptions-what-should-be-passed-to-the-options

Comment: Apparently the plugin you are using doesn't handle submission like I thought. Here is the documentation on your plugin. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api

Comment: No you can use the plugin if you want. (It's not necessary as doing this without plugins is pretty easy as well). You just aren't currently using the plugin correctly. Read the documentation on the plugin to see how it's used. It would appear English may not be your first language so I feel you there, but it's going to be hard without reading it as you won't really know what is going on. Otherwise Raj's answer does about what you want if you change `#response` to `#success` and his doesn't require a plugin.

Comment: I read the Raj's answer, I change my code with the code that he posted. But this doesn't working.. You can see here the result: http://blueberrylab.hostinggratis.it/cloudbackup/index3#contact ... and here I have update the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nl9mwsvb2gqccfg/landing.zip?dl=0 ... I'm completely confused

Comment: What's not working about his? Does it do anything. is there an error? Does it send the email? Also, he's missing a `{}` on his answer. Should be `$('#submit').click(function(e){` and at the end `)}`. Also, you left in `path/to/file`. That should be the REAL path to your submission page.

Comment: I feel like you are in way over your head man. You need to read the jQuery documentation on `.ajax` or `.post` to get a handle on what is happening and how it all works. We can explain in a few sentences all the nuances of submitting via ajax.

Comment: I just made EDIT2. Try that code. Also, open the developer tools in Chrome/FireFox/IE and look at the web console for errors.

Answer (score -2):

You could use if submit button was clicked and all filled out then redirect to success_page.php Just add name="submit" and it should work HTML:

**UPDATE 2 :** Working Example --->> [sample website](https://tadzik9634.000webhostapp.com/test.php) (DOnt mind the errors its just a quick example you can play around with it yourself. I added the php into the html file and it work. Hopfully this will help you.

**UPDATE:** If you `include` your php page in the div you want it should print out the message.

```html
<form class="contact-form" role="form" method="post" action="">
  <i class="mdi-action-account-box"></i>

  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Nome" required="required">

  <i class="mdi-content-mail"></i>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">

  <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Messaggio" rows="4" required="required"></textarea>

  <input type="checkbox" name="trattdati" required /> Accetto il trattamento dei miei dati ai sensi del D.Lgs. 196/03<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="provasoftware" /> Desidero provare il software
  <br /><br />
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" style="float:left">Invia</button>
  <?php
     
        $errorMSG = "";
        
        // NAME
        if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
            $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
        } else {
            $name = $_POST["name"];
        }
        
        // EMAIL
        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
        } else {
            $email = $_POST["email"];
        }
        
        // MSG SUBJECT
        //if (empty($_POST["msg_subject"])) {
        //    $errorMSG .= "Subject is required ";
        //} else {
        //    $msg_subject = $_POST["msg_subject"];
        //}
        
        
        // MESSAGE
        if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
            $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
        } else {
            $message = $_POST["message"];
        }
        
        
        $EmailTo = "bagiacchimarco7@gmail.com";
        $Subject = "New Message Received";
        
        // prepare email body text
        $Body = "";
        $Body .= "Name: ";
        $Body .= $name;
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Email: ";
        $Body .= $email;
        $Body .= "\n";
        //$Body .= "Subject: ";
        //$Body .= $msg_subject;
        //$Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= "Message: ";
        $Body .= $message;
        $Body .= "\n";
        
        // send email
        $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);
        
        // redirect to success page
        if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
           echo "success message sent!";
        }else{
            if($errorMSG == ""){
                echo "Something went wrong :(";
            } else {
                echo $errorMSG;
            }
        }
?>



    <div id="success" class="success" style="    color: #009688;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: -16px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How do I add a text string to the index page under the contact form? To avoid the new php page. Anyway thank you for the answer.

Comment: If updated my anwser you can include the php you have and it should do the trick

Comment: I upload the file here http://blueberrylab.hostinggratis.it/cloudbackup/index2 and if you send the contact form, will be open the page http://blueberrylab.hostinggratis.it/cloudbackup/php/form-process.php ... and not add the text under the form

Comment: I modified the file as you suggested, but it still does not work .. you can see the result here: http://blueberrylab.hostinggratis.it/cloudbackup/index2#contact ..

Answer (score -2):

You need to send a POST request via AJAX to your PHP file and handle the response on the DOM.

jQuery/AJAX code

```
$('#submit').click(function(e)
   e.preventDefault() //Prevent the default action of the form.
 $.post( //Send a POST request to the PHP file via AJAX
  "path/to/file.php", //Path to the PHP file where you want to send the POST
  $(.contact-form).serializeArray().reduce(function(obj, item) {
            obj[item.name] = item.value;
            return obj;
        }, {}) // This takes all the form fields and returns key-value pairs of form data

      , function (data) { //data = response from the PHP file. In your case "Sucess"
            if(data==="success"){
                //do something with data. Have assumed you want to append it to a div called "response". You will need to add <div id="response"> </div> below your form
                $('#response').html(data);
            } else {
                $('#response').html("Sorry Try Again"); 
            }
           //Alternatively you can just append data to response and not have this IF
        });
  )
```

Also do check out [validate.js](https://validatejs.org/). It handles validation of the form on the front end itself and also has a really nice method to submit forms and manage responses.

Comment: It looks like he's using a `ajaxForm` plugin that isn't preventing the default behavior of the form submission.